# search a value inside a list and find its key in python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

suppose the dictionary contains a list like this and I want to find if "name" exists in the dictionary then find its key in python..... anyone can help?

```
test_dict = { "what is your name" :['name',"what's your name",'tell me your name ?'],
              "time" : ['time','whats the time'] }
```

so the expected output of search 'name' would look like 'what is your name' !

Comment: And what if the name contains in both of the list then?

Answer (score 0):

You only need a [comprehension list](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension), like this:

```
test_dict = { "what is your name" :['name',"what's your name",'tell me your name ?'],
              "time" : ['time','whats the time'] }

results = [k for k,v in test_dict.items() if "name" in v]
```

Comment: its not working on [k for k,v in test_dict.items() if "nilanjan" in v]  and the test dict is                            
test_dict = { "what is your name" :["what's your name","tell me your name","nilanjan"],
              "time" : ['time','whats the time'],
              "backup my code" : ["backup","git add all"]}

Answer (score 0):

**You only need a [comprehension list][1], like this:
(fixed)**

```
test_dict = { "what is your name" :['name',"what's your name",'tell me your name ?'],"time" : ['time','whats the time'] }
for t_d in test_dict:
    results = [k for k,v in t_d.items() if "name" in v]

print("100"*100)
print(results)
print("100"*100)
```